# How to get internal resource pointer from a MySql result set in Php?

Tags: php, mysql

methods like mysql_fetch_array move the internal resource pointer on a MySql result set, but how do you get the current value of the internal resource pointer though?  Is there a "mysql_" method that returns this value?

Comment: why do you need this? what are you trying to do?

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but mysql_ are deprecated. Use mysqli_ or PDO

Comment: well, I wrote a method that grabs the same record twice as it loops through, but pulls different fields from it and sets different DTO's each time.  Here's how I do it:
mysql_data_seek($this->rs, --$this->count);

so, in this case the internal resource pointer is mimicked by $this->count, but I don't see why I can't just grab it from the result set and not duplicate functionality.

btw the reason i'm doing this is that I'm returning a list of playlists of videos.  so, each record has the playlist data and the data of the video.  I test to see when the playlist id changes and create new pl dto

Comment: @Evert Where's your information on the the mysql_* functions being depreciated?  They're certainly older functions, but I've seen nothing that indicated they've been deprciated in 5.3 or 6

Comment: I don't think they're deprecated (yet), but for several reasons (security, prepared statements (!!!), speed, other MySQL 5 features, ...) you really should use mysqli_* or PDO. I prefer the latter.

Answer (score 0):

[mysql_connect()](http://php.net/mysql_connect) returns the resource you might be looking for.

> mysql_connect — Open a connection to a
>   MySQL Server
>
> Return Values
>
> Returns a MySQL link identifier on
>   success, or FALSE on failure.

Unless I'm misunderstanding..

Comment: yeah, I'm talking about iterating through the result set returned from mysql_query.
ex:
$rs = mysql_query($query);

Comment: mysql_fetch_array() or mysql_fetch_assoc() or mysql_fetch_row().. there's quite a few more options but most of the time any of those will meet your needs.